# Master Shared Layout Header with Login Form in MVC 4 using asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, master-pages, partial-views

I want to develop Login Form  Header(header.cshtml) that is avialble in Layout.cshtml(shared),

My Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/boxOver.js"></script>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main_container">
                @Html.Partial("_Header")
            <div id="body">
                @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                    @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </div>

                    @Html.Partial("_Footer")
            </div>
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

and the _Header.cshtml like this

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div id="header">
        <input name="login_username" class="textbox" placeholder="Username" type="text">
    <input name="login_password" class="textbox"  placeholder="Pasword" type="text">
    <input name="login" class="button" value="login" type="submit">
    <input name="login" class="button" value="Register" type="submit">
<div id="logo"> <a href=""><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" border="0" width="182" height="85" /></a> </div>
</div>
```

Here _Header.cshtml is a shared partial view. I want to develop this view with model and controller with database connection in master(Layout.cshtml) as partial view Using MVC 4 in .net.

The Header is like the below image,[Header Html Layout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIlvD.png)

Comment: Can you ask your question more clearly?

Comment: Use `@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml"; }` for every view page which uses master header layout, can you show controller code to find out how pages with header layout has loaded?